# What is the intuitive sense of the expected value of the sum of two random variables

Tags: distributions, mean, random-variable, joint-distribution

I completely understand what is the intuitive sense of the single R.V mean. However, I was solving a math problem to find the expected value of the sum of two independent random variable, which is can be found by

$$\mathbb E[x+y] = \int (x+y) p(x) p(y)\, dx \,dy\tag 1$$

So I said, yes it makes sense, since we want to find the expected value for **both** of the two random variable. Then I criticized myself by two points

1. What does **both** mean here? That two of the event occur? That is the product of the two R.V not the sum! So it makes sense to write an equation for $\mathbb E[x+y] = \int (x+y) p(x) p(y) \,dx\, dy$
2. If we write the equation $(1)$ as $\mathbb E[x+y] = \int x p(x) p(y)\, dx \,dy + \int y p(x) p(y) \,dx\, dy$. What does each term mean? What is the meaning (if we take the first term) of finding the average of random variable $X$ over the probability of $X$ and $Y$?

I did not find answers to those questions.

Comment: The language used in this question suggests there may be some underlying misunderstanding of what a random variable is, because it seems to be confused with an "event."  Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50 for clarification.  Concerning (2), the terms are the expectations of $X$ and $Y$, *by definition.*

Comment: @whuber It seems yes, I didn't realize that :)

Answer (score 4):

Recall that for any random variables $X$ and $Y$ with a joint probability distribution function $p(x,y)$, the expected value of $X+Y$ is
$$ \mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[X+Y] = \int_x\int_y (x+y) p(x,y) dydx = \int_x x \int_y p(x,y)dydx + \int_y y \int_x p(x,y) dxdy$$

In the special case that $x$ and $y$ are independent, $p(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y)$ and we can write the integral in the form that you had it, where $p_X$ is the marginal probability distribution of $X$ and $p_Y$ the marginal probability distribution of $Y$:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \int_x\int_y (x+y) p_X(x)p_Y(y) dydx$$

This is where the "product" is coming from - it represents the (infinitesmal) probability that $X=x$ and $Y=y$, which we use to weight $x+y$ appropriately when computing the expected value of $X+Y$.  Think of it as searching over all possible combinations of $X$ and $Y$, and for each combination you are evaluating the value of $X+Y$ and weighting it by the probability the combination occurs.

Since you are already adding two random variables, presumably there is a meaning to the sum of the variables. For example if it is travel time, $X$ could be the time it takes for the first trip, $Y$ for the second, and $X+Y$ is the total duration. $\mathbb{E}[X+Y]$ is the expected time of the total trip.

Linearity of expectation might help out a bit for understanding the last question. Remember that $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$. For the independent case, if you simplify the two integrals you'll get 
$$ \mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \int_X x p_X(x) dx + \int_Y yp_Y(y)dy$$
the first integral is the expected value of $X$, the second term is the expected value of $Y$. In the travel example, you would expected the total trip time to be the expected time of the first trip plus the expected time of the second trip.

Comment: Thanks. How would you interpret the E[x.y] based on your example?

Comment: You mean the product? I am unsure what you mean by $x.y$.

Comment: Yes the product.

Comment: Interpretation would depend on the random variables. An example would be where $x$ is the percent return of an investment you make starting in a year, while $y$ is the amount you have available to invest in a year. Then $xy$ would be the amount you get at the end of the investment, and $\mathbb{E}[xy]$ its expected value, where the expectation is taken over uncertainty in the returns ($x$) and uncertainty in how much you have available to invest ($y$).

Comment: This answer starts out correctly but then degenerates into something that seems to suggest that linearity of expectation holds only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  What is missing is the realization that in the very first displayed formula above, $\int_y p(x,y)dy$ and $\int_x p(x,y)dx$ have values $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$ respectively and so **even when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent**, $$E[X+Y]=\int_x xp_X(x)dx + \int_yyp_Y(y)dy=E[X]+E[Y].$$. -1 pending corrections and improvement of notation. It is generally accepted that a symbol should mean the same thing wherever it occurs....

Comment: (continued)...  Try that on $$\int_x xp(x)dx + \int_y yp(y)dy$$ where $p$ stands for two entirely different functions depending on what the argument is instead of the generally accepted notion that $p(x)$ is the value of the function $p(\cdot)$ at $x$ and $p(y)$ the value of the **same function** at $y$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate re "generally accepted": the usage of $p(\cdot)$ for different pdfs to be inferred from context is (unfortunately?) common in some circles, e.g. Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman et al. uses this. (I agree that the notation $p_X(\cdot)$ is better here)

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables (defined on the same probability space: ignore this remark if it confuses you), then we can regard $(X,Y)$ as a *random vector* (also called a *bivariate* random variable) and $X$ and $Y$ individually as special kinds of *functions* of $(X,Y)$ -- called projections or projection maps if you want to use fancy words. Another function of $(X,Y)$ is $X+Y$ (called the "sum" function, of course, what else?) and what this means is that if on a particular trial of the experiment, $X$ and $Y$ took on values $x$ and $y$ respectively (equivalently, $(X,Y)$ had value $(x,y)$), then this sum random variable (denote it by $Z$) has taken on value $x+y$ on this particular trial. There is no notion of "both occurring"; as whuber points out in his comment, you are confusing the concepts of events and random variables.

So, if $W$ is a random variable, what is $E[g(W)]$, the expected value of the  *function* $V = g(W)$ of the random variable $W$? There are two standard ways of finding the answer: if we know, or can determine, 
the distribution of $V$, then we can use the definition of expectation. For example, if $V$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f_V(v)$, then $$E[V] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty v\cdot f_V(v) \,\mathrm dv.$$
Alternatvely, we can use the 
[Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) 
or LOTUS and determine the value of $E[V]=E[g(W)]$ as
$$E[V]=E[g(W)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(w)\cdot f_W(w) \,\mathrm dw$$
where $f_W(w)$ is the pdf of $W$. Now, LOTUS applies to functions
of bivariate (and more generally multivariate) random variables also,
and we can find $E[Z] =E[X+Y]$ via
$$E[Z]=E[X+Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x+y)\cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx  \,\mathrm dy\tag{1}$$ where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is
the *joint* pdf of $X$ and $Y$ or just the pdf of the *bivariate*
random variable $(X,Y)$. As a special case, when $X$ and $Y$ are
*independent* random variables, $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, and so we get the formula shown in your question. But
it is very important that you understand that $(1)$ always holds, regardless of independence etc (for jointly continuous random variables).

A funny thing happens on the way to the forum as one massages the forumula $(1)$. We have that
\begin{align}
E[X+Y] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x+y)\cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx  \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx  \,\mathrm dy + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx  \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dy  \,\mathrm dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx  \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dy \right] \,\mathrm dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty  f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx\right]  \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \cdot f_{X}(x) \,\mathrm dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty y\cdot f_{Y}(y)  \,\mathrm dy\\
E[X+Y] &= E[X] + E[Y]\tag{2}
\end{align}
The result $(2)$ is a special case of the *linearity of expectation*
because the argument above can be applied to show that $E[aX+bY] = aE[X]+bE[Y]$, that is, expectation behaves like a linear operation
with respect to random variables: the expectation of a weighted sum
is the weighted sum of the expectations.

> Linearity of expectation is a very general result. It holds for all
>   random variables, not just the jointly continuous ones as in the calculation above, or for independent random variables only as the answer by Stefan Jorgenson seems to be suggesting.